# Maven org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

Greeting,
I got the following error "org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException",  "Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" when I try to run compiled project through console by java -jar "name of the file".jar. It runs without problems when started trough the IDE. The problem is caused by the external jar file that is used in the project, but I cant figure it out why. I managed to find some information about the problem here, but the solutions did not worked for me. That is why I opened new topic.

This is the pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.5</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.project</groupId>
<artifactId>fingerprintId</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>fingerprintId</name>
<description>Fingerprint identification service with external library</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <mainClass>com.project.fingerprintId.FingerprintIdApplication</mainClass>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ImageSDK</groupId>
        <artifactId>ImageSDK</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${pom.basedir}/src/lib/ImageSDK.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>fingerprintIdentificationService</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <mainClass>com.project.fingerprintId.FingerprintIdApplication</mainClass>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The error I get in console:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataHandlerController' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/hristo.lihov/test/Fingerprint_identification/target/fingerprintIdentification.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/fingerprintIdentification/controller/DataHandlerController.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/suprema/ImageSDK
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1316) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar!/:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar!/:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar!/:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar!/:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar!/:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar!/:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar!/:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar!/:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar!/:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar!/:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar!/:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar!/:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar!/:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:438) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar!/:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:337) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar!/:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1336) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar!/:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1325) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar!/:2.5.0]
    at fingerprintIdentification.FingerprintIdentificationApplication.main(FingerprintIdentificationApplication.java:14) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[fingerprintIdentification.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[fingerprintIdentification.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[fingerprintIdentification.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[fingerprintIdentification.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/suprema/ImageSDK
    at fingerprintIdentification.controller.DataHandlerController.<clinit>(DataHandlerController.java:24) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:212) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar!/:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar!/:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar!/:5.3.7]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.suprema.ImageSDK
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151) ~[fingerprintIdentification.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
```

Comment: The issue is related to this: `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/suprema/ImageSDK` and to the system scoped dependency. The issue is by default the spring-boot-maven-plugin does not package such dependencies. You have to configure the plugin to add the system scoped deps as well. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.5.RELEASE/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html#includeSystemScope

Comment: I would hardly asked why you have a system scoped dependency in your project instead of using the usual maven mechanisms...

Comment: I'm new at this technologies. That's why it looks the way it is. When project was started, I added the jar in External libraries and the project worked. Now I have to compile and run it on server. That was the point where I start to search for solution, the result is what you see. The project depends on that external jar and I need  solution how to use it when project is compiled. That is the end goal.

Comment: Yes, I managed to run it when included system scope.
Thank you.